# LinkedList remove all Strings that begin with _______

Tags: list

Is it possible to remove all strings in a LinkedList that begins with a specific 
beginning like 'remove'.?

If you need any more information please say it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? SO users surely want to help you, but please show some effort first, since SO is no free coding service. Oh..what language are we talking about? `LinkedList` looks like c#, but please add the correct tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) over the LinkedList and use the Iterator's [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) operation;

```java
LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();
myList.add("do not remove");
myList.add("remove this");

Iterator iter = myList.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext())
{
    String value = (String)iter.next();
    if(value.startsWith("remove"))
        iter.remove();
}

// Only "do not remove" remains
```